# Deploying mezzanine site on DigitalOcean with Fabric

Tags: rsync, mezzanine

I'm trying to deploy my mezzanine site and have been following this [tutorial](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html) using CASE 1 (to new server)

- 1-3 all seems fine (obviously not) till I get to step 4
- 4- Run fab all

The process installs virtualenvs, and in it a directory with my project name and then I get this error:

> [1xx.xx.xxx.xx] out: New python executable in /home/~/.virtualenvs/blog_iq/bin/python [1xx.xx.xxx.xx] out:
>   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done. [1xx.xx.xxx.xx]] out:
>   [1xx.xx.xxx.xx]] rsync_project: rsync  --exclude "*.pyc" --exclude
>   "*.pyo" --exclude "*.db" --exclude ".DS_Store" --exclude ".coverage"
>   --exclude "local_settings.py" --exclude "/static" --exclude "/.git" --exclude "/.hg" -pthrvz  --rsh='ssh  -p 22 ' C:\Users\~\Root\2blog\blog_iq\
>   user@1xx.xxx.xx:/home/user/mezzanine/blog_iq
>
> [localhost] local: rsync  --exclude "*.pyc" --exclude "*.pyo"
>   --exclude "*.db" --exclude ".DS_Store" --exclude ".coverage" --exclude "local_settings.py" --exclude "/static" --exclude "/.git" --exclude
>   "/.hg" -pthrvz  --rsh='ssh  -p 22  ' C:\Users\~\Root\2blog\blog_iq\
>   user@1xx.xxx.xx:/home/user/mezzanine/blog_iq
>
> The source and destination cannot both be remote. rsync error: syntax
>   or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1292) [Receiver=3.1.2]
>
> Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while
>   executing 'rsync  --exclude "*.pyc" --exclude "*.pyo" --exclude "*.db"
>   --exclude ".DS_Store" --exclude ".coverage" --exclude "local_settings.py" --exclude "/static" --exclude "/.git" --exclude
>   "/.hg" -pthrvz  --rsh='ssh  -p 22  ' C:\Users\~\Root\2blog\blog_iq\
>   user@1xx.xxx.xx:/home/user/mezzanine/blog_iq
>
> Aborting. Disconnecting from 1xx.xxx.xx... done.

I'll gladly post the entire fabfile.py that was generated by mezzanine upon installation but it's a lengthy one and I never touched it except for looking for the code that's generating this printout and it seems to be here:

```
################
# Config setup #
################

if not hasattr(env, "proj_app"):
    env.proj_app = real_project_name("blog_iq")

conf = {}
if sys.argv[0].split(os.sep)[-1] in ("fab", "fab-script.py"):
    # Ensure we import settings from the current dir
    try:
        conf = import_module("%s.settings" % env.proj_app).FABRIC
        try:
            conf["HOSTS"][0]
        except (KeyError, ValueError):
            raise ImportError
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        print("Aborting, no hosts defined.")
        exit()


env.db_pass = conf.get("DB_PASS", None)
env.admin_pass = conf.get("ADMIN_PASS", None)
env.user = conf.get("SSH_USER", getuser())
env.password = conf.get("SSH_PASS", None)
env.key_filename = conf.get("SSH_KEY_PATH", None)
env.hosts = conf.get("HOSTS", [""])

env.proj_name = conf.get("PROJECT_NAME", env.proj_app)
env.venv_home = conf.get("VIRTUALENV_HOME", "/home/%s/.virtualenvs" % env.user)
env.venv_path = join(env.venv_home, env.proj_name)
env.proj_path = "/home/%s/mezzanine/%s" % (env.user, env.proj_name)
env.manage = "%s/bin/python %s/manage.py" % (env.venv_path, env.proj_path)
env.domains = conf.get("DOMAINS", [conf.get("LIVE_HOSTNAME", env.hosts[0])])
env.domains_nginx = " ".join(env.domains)
env.domains_regex = "|".join(env.domains)
env.domains_python = ", ".join(["'%s'" % s for s in env.domains])
env.ssl_disabled = "#" if len(env.domains) > 1 else ""
env.vcs_tools = ["git", "hg"]
env.deploy_tool = conf.get("DEPLOY_TOOL", "rsync")
env.reqs_path = conf.get("REQUIREMENTS_PATH", None)
env.locale = conf.get("LOCALE", "en_US.UTF-8")
env.num_workers = conf.get("NUM_WORKERS",
                           "multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1")

env.secret_key = conf.get("SECRET_KEY", "")
env.nevercache_key = conf.get("NEVERCACHE_KEY", "")

if not env.secret_key:
    print("Aborting, no SECRET_KEY setting defined.")
    exit()


# Remote git repos need to be "bare" and reside separated from the project
if env.deploy_tool == "git":
    env.repo_path = "/home/%s/git/%s.git" % (env.user, env.proj_name)
else:
    env.repo_path = env.proj_path
```

and here

```
def rsync_upload():
    """
    Uploads the project with rsync excluding some files and folders.
    """
    excludes = ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.db", ".DS_Store", ".coverage",
                "local_settings.py", "/static", "/.git", "/.hg"]
    local_dir = os.getcwd() + os.sep
    return rsync_project(remote_dir=env.proj_path, local_dir=local_dir,
                         exclude=excludes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `rsync` interprets `C:` as a remote server, because of the column.

I suppose you had to install `CygWin` along with `rsync`: then use CygWin-like paths : `/cygdrive/c/...`